# Spring 4 - Spring Boot - SOA - JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

im writing a service to import order into an erp-system.

here there scenario of the unit-test marked with spring transactional annotation as read-only:

1. loading a product and creating an order.
2. import the order into the erp via soap
3. checking the products stock-collection for changes

so there is the problem in point 3. the products-collection won't re-select the database to get the new stock values changed outside spring app.

the products stocks-collection is loaded lazily.

i could write a separate query to load a specific stock from database, but i'd like to know if there is a way to refresh the collection inside this read-only transaction.

i tried to refresh the object via the entity manager like : em.refresh(product) but this didn't
work.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Clear the entitymanager (first flush!) and load the product if you don't it will be retrieved from the first level cache.

Comment: tried that as you suggested. it didn't work. any other clues ?

Comment: Then you either haven't cleared it correctly and it still lingers around somewhere or you are using a second level cache which still holds a reference. You also need to make sure that you are actually reloading and checking the reloaded entity not the entity you already had, that will not be updated!

Comment: ok. i tried to flush() and did a find() which didn't work, tried the same with annotating the classed with coachable(value = false), didn't work either.

Comment: I said **clear** not **flush** But before clearing you need to flush else your changes will get lost. So first do `em.flush()` then `em.clear(). If that doesn't work and you still have your old values the database didn't update (maybe the other side didn't commit yet).

Comment: mea culpa, shame on me. your absolutely right!!! and it works great. thanks a lot!